# c2i_ASN1_INTEGER function in Openssl 1.1.0

Tags: openssl

I recently updated openssl from 1.0.2n to 1.1.0g in linux system.

Earlier I was using

`ASN1_INTEGER *c2i_ASN1_INTEGER(ASN1_INTEGER **a, const unsigned char **pp, long len)`  function. As this function is removed in openssl 1.1.0, now i replaced this with

`ASN1_INTEGER *d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER(ASN1_INTEGER **a, const unsigned char **pp, long length)` .

Now when i run my application then i get warning as

`Warning:0:-- SSL Error queue report --
Warning:0: - asn1 encoding routines|d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER|expecting an integer:218718323`

What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASN.1 encoding of an INTEGER (as BER or DER) consists of 1 or more "identifier" octets (usually 1), followed by 1 or more "length" octets, followed by "content" octets (the length of which is determined by the previous "length" octets).

The function `c2i_ASN1_INTEGER` assumes you have already parsed the "identifier" and "length" octets and coverts the "content" bytes into an integer. This was removed from OpenSSL 1.1.0 because this is considered a very low level parsing operation that applications should not be calling directly.

The function `d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER` is not a direct drop in replacement for `c2i_ASN1_INTEGER`. It parses the whole integer (including the "identifier" and "length" octets). If you pass it just the content octets then it will interpret the first byte as an "identifier" octet. This will likely have the wrong value for an integer and so this is probably why you are seeing the "expecting an integer" error.

You will need to rewrite your code to pass the whole integer to `d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER`.

Comment: Hi @Matt Thanks for your answer. As i was going though some of the links, i thought that i can directly replace c2i by d2i function. Can you suggest me the code how to parse ientifier and length from whole integer.

Comment: That's a very difficult question to answer. Basically in order to replace c2i_ASN_INTEGER with d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER you have to remove whatever code you had for parsing the identifier and and length. Since I don't know what your code looks like, I can't really advise on how to remove that parsing.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the reply. I thought there may be a new API for parsing. Anyway I will try it out. Thanks again

Comment: @Matt According to this article https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/receipt-validation/  
How to get d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER to work with openssl above 1.1.0? thanks

Comment: That's really a separate question which probably doesn't belong in the comments section of this answer.

Comment: Use d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER only if you expect a positive integer, otherwise use d2i_ASN1_INTEGER.

Comment: here also solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932816/11079607](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932816/11079607)

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of some code that uses `c2i_ASN1_INTEGER()`.

```
ASN1_get_object(&ptr, &length, &type, &xclass, end - ptr);
if (type == V_ASN1_INTEGER) {
    integer = c2i_ASN1_INTEGER(NULL, &ptr, length);
    value = ASN1_INTEGER_get(integer);
    ASN1_INTEGER_free(integer);

    // do something with value
} else
    ptr += length;
```

Here's how I modified the code to use `d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER()` instead.

```
save_ptr = ptr;
ASN1_get_object(&ptr, &length, &type, &xclass, end - ptr);
if (type == V_ASN1_INTEGER) {
    ptr = save_ptr;
    integer = d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER(NULL, &ptr, end - ptr);
    value = ASN1_INTEGER_get(integer);
    ASN1_INTEGER_free(integer);

    // do something with value
} else
    ptr += length;
```

First I saved `ptr` in `save_ptr`. `ASN1_get_object()` takes `ptr` pointing to the beginning of the BER/DER. `ASN1_get_object()` updates `ptr` to point to the content. `c2i_ASN1_INTEGER()` takes `ptr` pointing to the content, advances `ptr` beyond the content to point to the beginning of the next BER/DER, and returns an `ASN1_INTEGER`.

Now `d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER()` returns an `ASN1_INTEGER` too but it needs to take `ptr` pointing to the beginning of the BER/DER.  So I simply set `ptr` back to its value before `ASN1_get_object()` was called. `d2i_ASN1_UINTEGER()` takes `ptr` pointing the beginning of the BER/DER, advances `ptr` to the beginning of the next BER/DER, and returns an `ASN1_INTEGER`.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Worked great for me. Thank you, KGBird.